# Epson WorkForce 633 not detected over network

Tags: windows-10, printer, network-printer

I have an Epson WorkForce 633 printer connected over the network to an old win10 laptop. Its driver shows up in the device manager and the printer shows up in the windows printer and scanners settings. It prints without problem.

However, on a newer win10 laptop, I have installed the drivers from the Epson site as well as the software. The driver also shows up in the device manager, but no matter what I do, the computer will not find the printer over the network.

When going to add a printer, it doesn't show up on both devices, but when clicking "the printer that I want isn't listed" then "my printer is a little older. Help me find it", the old computer that works finds it whereas the new computer still doesn't find it.

I am helping out a neighbour so I own none of these devices but am trying to fix it for them.

Comment: Is file and printer sharing enabled on the newer w10 laptop?

Comment: How is the printer physically connected: USB, WiFi or wired network?